# Jagged circles while slicing in Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I am having some issues where I am seeing small jagged lines on the final inner walls of G-code generated by Cura, is there anything I can do to try and reduce this.

I am seeing both jagged circles as well as stitching? between some perimeters.

I think this is caused by some interaction between trying to print the top surface of the model and the walls.

[image]

Below the red line roughly shows where these are occurring in my model.

[image]

I have tried both Cura 4.7 & 4.8 does anyone have suggestions on what I can do to help get rid of these artifacts, or should I not worry about them, I am just concerned about them affecting the strength of my print as this is an engineering component.

Comment: possibly an artifact created by the number of walls... have you the same issue if you try less walls?

Comment: I require the number of walls to make some of the thin sections of my part solid.

Comment: I don't dspute that, but there is something in the geometry that creates an infill movement in between the inner layers and the 3 towards the infill - that's ODD...

Comment: I will try when I get home, I was suspicious of interaction with the top layer, I have perimeters set to 5, with alternate extra turned on. The issue appears to happen from the 9th outline which I can only assume is coming from the top surface.

Comment: I get this sometimes. Adjust the layer width up or down a bit in order to kill the aliasing. It's also not a huge deal in terms of finished strength; I just hate the way it sounds when laying down "jaggies".

Comment: Alternatively, use a good slicer instead.

Comment: @towe, what a useful comment, if you are going to be condescending at least make an actual suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion: Use a slicer that isn't known to produce erratic g-code on round objects. That the most useful it's going to get if you insist on using obsolete software.